# Help for a small project for a small small electrical circuit

Tags: audio, music

I'm planing on making a small electrical circuit built in to a card or a little box, which starts playing a little melody (in my case Rick Astley - Never Gonna Give You Up) in 8 bit sound, when you open the box/card. Like those x-mas cards which the jingle of some x-mas starts playing.
What do I need? (Please keep in mind that I'm very new to setting up circuits) How long might it take?

Link to melody: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HsOt7H4ZShc&noredirect=1  (Planing on just having the refrain going on repeat until you close the box/card)

Comment: how long might it take? Do you mean rick astley's classic, learning the ropes or building the circuit. Bear also in mind that if it's a Xmas present you ain't got much time left unless it's for next year.

Comment: Nah, the question about time was more, how much time I need to put off for it, so I can plan it in to my schedule.

Comment: Actually doing it won't take long. Learning how will.

Comment: The recordable playback device from an audio postcard may be available separately as an OEM.  I remember that I came across that on some forum a few years ago.

Comment: Have we just been rickrolled?

Answer (score 2):

Phase 1. Strip the sound off the youtube video and using something like wavelab or audacity, reduce the sampling rate and bit count and see what it sounds like playing over your PC - be really mean with this because the miniature speaker needed for a xmas card will sound really crappy anyway. Maybe you can also filter out all the bass as well because this will not be needed playing it back thru the crappy speaker. In fact the bass will make things worse - you just need to concentrate on frequencies probably between 500 Hz and 2 kHz. Mono of course!

Cut the song (with its reduced sample rate and bit resolution) to the length you need and see how big the file is. Next, find an MCU that you can programme that can store the file in a small memory device and write some code to playback the snippet of the song. You'll probably need to learn how to extract the header stuff from the wav file because you won't be needing this. That's phase 2.

Phase 3 is getting it to work on a small battery supply with a small amplifier. The MCU you choose ought to be able to run at sub 3V3 to increase battery choices. You might find that you can output the data thru a port designed for pulse width modulation - this can virtually feed directly to the speaker if you choose the right device.

That's how I'd do it anyway if I weren't such a xmas grumpo.

Comment: Related reading: http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/PCMAudio - http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc2572.pdf - http://www.winbond.com/hq/enu/ProductAndSales/ProductLines/FlashMemory/SerialFlash/

Answer (score 0):

Look for X-mas cards that let you record your own sounds and play it back in 8-bit-ish sound. These exist (I have seen/tested them) so if you really just want the product and skip the Do-It-Yourself part I suggest you do that.

Comment: Ah! What might thses device cost and what name do they go by?